# SQL request with date comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, dateinterval

I have a trouble concerning my request, and my date column.

Here is my table `event`:

- id (int, pk, ai)
- date (datetime)
- location (char)
- link (char)

I would like to display 6 events on my page. The 3 last, and the next 3, compared to today's date. But my request doesn't work.

I think I have to use `between`, and `now()` and `datediff` but mysql send me a syntax error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM events
WHERE (date BETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() - 3 days) AND NOW()) 
   OR (date BETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() + 3 days) AND NOW())
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 6
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you actually filtering or you just want it sorted so you can paginate? What RDBMS are you using, update your question with that as a tag.

Comment: i'm using mysql as rdbms. I want to get 6 date, 3 before today, and 3 next today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATEDIFF returns the difference of time between two points of time. So between yesterday and today the DATEDIFF might be 24 hours. You are potentially telling it to return a date between 24 and 2016-02-23. That doesn't make much sense. I think you meant to use DATE_ADD.